# ¿Cargar un array lleno con una consulta en un <script>?

Tags: php, javascript, array

la cosa es que tengo un .php que devuelve un array con un enlace ("http://localhost/") y un nombre_serie. Como tengo otra función que utiliza un keyup, lo que quiero hacer es cargar el array y mientras que vas escribiendo que salga el nombre de la serie como un link.

```
 function autocompletado() {
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = '';

    var links=<?php echo $links>?;

         var pal = document.getElementById("buscarPalabra").value;
         var tam = pal.length;
         for(indice in links){
            var nombre = links[indice];
            var str = nombre.substring(0,tam);
            if(pal.length <= nombre.length && pal.length != 0 && nombre.length != 0){
                if(pal.toLowerCase() == str.toLowerCase()){
                    var node = document.createElement("a");
                    var textnode = document.createTextNode(links[indice]);
                    node.href = indice;
                    node.appendChild(textnode);
                    document.getElementById("resultado").appendChild(node);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Esto es la conexión.

```
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT enlace, nombre_serie FROM buscador" ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Creamos array con los datos
            $fila = array($row["enlace"]=>$row["nombre_serie"]);

            //Almacenamos los datos en el array original
            array_push($links, $fila);
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
```

Me sale que nombre.substring no es una función. Alguna idea, he visto que se puede hacer con php en vez de js.

Comment: Deberías describir mejor qué es lo que intentas conseguir.

Comment: Te falta explicar mejor que quieres, y que contiene esas variables. Pero así de primeras, aquí `for(indice in links){
            var nombre = links[indice];` hay algo que pinta muy mal. Indice es una variable equivalente a una de las posiciones del array links. Creo que deberías repasar como funciona el for in.

Comment: Ese función hace su trabajo con un array manual. El problema viene con cargar el array desde el php.

Comment: Si el array es  var links = {
"http://localhost":"FRIENDS"};     Si que la función funciona correctamente.

Comment: lo suyo seria que hicieras una llamada ajax al php, para devolver los datos que te interesan, y luego en el propio javascript recibir los datos. normalmente se hace con datos tipo Json (en tu caso no se ve que devuelves. Por otra parte, tu php deberia devolver SIEMPRE un valor, aunque fuera un array vacio. En tu caso, creas un array o, en caso de no tenerlo muestras una cadena. Este ultimo caso deberia ser un array vacio.

Answer (score 1):

Casi seguro que `var links=<?php echo $links>?;` no funciona. Si quieres conservar tu código en javascript prueba a recorrer tu array de php con un foreach de php para rellenar la variable de javascript correctamente. Esta sería la solución más rápida sin cambiar mucho tu código, aunque no la más eficiente

```
var links = [];
<?php foreach ($links as $key => $val): ?>
links[<?=$key?>]=<?=$val?>;
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Si quieres modificar todo el código y pasarlo a php ese foreach te sirve de la misma manera

Comment: Entonces lo que me falta es recorrer el array links del php y devolver un valor, para llamarlo luego en el js?

Comment: Partiendo de la base de que el resto de tu código es correcto lo que yo te he puesto reemplazaría a `var links=<?php echo $links>?;`

Comment: Unexpected token <  
                                  
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = '';
var links = [];
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: links in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\inicio.php</b> on line <b>174</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\inicio.php</b> on line <b>174</b><br /> ESTO SALE AHORA

Comment: Pues ahí lo que parece que sucede es que la variable $links no está inicializada al momento de generar ese Js... Igualmente, no olvides las comillas: links[<?=$key?>]='<?=$val?>';

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, al final tiré por otro camino , usé jquery mucho mas sencillo y con un LIKE% lo fuÍ haciendo.